# Как обратиться к <p:commandButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Всем привет Использую `Jsf (primefaces)`,реализовал форму `<h:form>` внутри `<p:dataTable>` а в нем `<p:columns>`  с кнопкой `<p:commandButton>` А проблема вот в чем у вех этих допустим 20 значений уникальные ID я немогу как то к ним обратится через Js помогите.МНе надо задать им толи класс толи еще чтото чтоб мог обращаться через js или jquery  ко всем сразу, прописал что тыкаешь кнопку выходит диалект и уже не указывшь какую именно .

Comment: Вопрос решен .Я нашел 2 выхода вответ приму также допалнения :

Answer (score 0):

```
> 1)Это или вытащить Таблицу из формы что не рекомендуется  2)Добавить
> параметры форме prepareId="false" тоже не рекомендуется так как после
> этого Jsf может работать не корректно. 3)Добавить 
> StyleCLass="myselector" и обращаться к нему точно также как и к классу
```